# Powerpoint 2003: Including TOC on each slide (like Latex beamer)

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, table-of-contents

Is there any way or template to make Powerpoint presentations that show the TOC showing the current progress on each slide?

I want to achieve something like what can be done using Beamer in LaTeX.

[image: Beamer slide with TOC on top]
(Example from http://outlinebeamer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: As of June 2020, anyone aware of official Microsoft support for this feature?

Answer (score 1):

PowerPoint won't do this for you.  You might be able to write code (VBA, etc) to pick up the slide title of each slide, add it to a "progress" area and highlight the current slide's title on each slide.

You might want to ask on http://answers.microsoft.com (the PowerPoint section) also.  Perhaps someone there has written something that'd do.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and just found this PowerPoint AddIn which automaticly makes this for you. It's free and has a lot of other features.

PowerPoint Labs:
http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~pptlabs/docs/agenda-lab.html

Comment: Thanks for that, @Pozsy.  Looks like a very useful add-in.  Unfortunately, it won't work for obaquiero because it depends on Sections within the PowerPoint file; that feature wasn't introduced until PPT 2010 or so but he mentions PPT 2003.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing out.